# Problem in sending data from classes through delegation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi i have a problem with pasing values to one class from other. Basically in my project i have a class placeTableView which is table view class.

```
in placesTableView.m
{
mapView *map=[[mapView alloc]init];
map.townName=@"london";

}


mapView.h - a class where delegate is defined and from this class i want to send data to     confirmController

@protocol mapViewDelegate; 

@interface mapView : UIViewController  { 


id <mapViewDelegate> delegate;// 
} 
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;// 


@end 
@protocol mapViewDelegate <NSObject>// 

-(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string; 
@end
```

mapView.m

```
@synthesis townName;
-(void)viewDidLoad{ 


label.text=townName;//townName is getting value from previous view n showing here.


NSLog(@"%@",townName);//it shows value of townName so townName definetly contains value

//  NSString *a=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",townName];

[delegate sendAStringToAnotherView:townName]; // this is sending method. i think problem is here
}
```

confirmController.m - a class where data sent

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{ 

mapView *myViewControllerPointer=[[mapView alloc] init]; 
myViewControllerPointer.delegate = self;// 

[self.view addSubview:self.myViewControllerPointer.view];

} 

-(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string 
{ 
//displays the string as console output 
NSLog(@"lolo%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string]); // i want to show values here
}
```

Now i want to show townName in `confirmController` from mapView. But it shows null. but in `mapView` if i use string in place of townName it shows here in `confirmController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create necessary variable in appDelegate and set its property in .h and Synthesize in .m file. now you can set value for this variable in your first class and get value to destination class using appDalegate variable

Comment: ok you are saying i have to declare variable in application delegate class. and again declare them and set their property in mapView class and in mapView.m file i can put values in them. and in confirmController class where i want to access them i can access them using application variable ? how please explian it more

Comment: or i have to set property n synthesis in application delegate class?

Comment: i set variable in application delegate class set property and sysnthsis there. now in my sender class how can i set values? my variable which i declared in application delegate class is globalVariable. but in sender class globalVariable is showin undeclared?

Comment: you have to set property in appDelegate.h and synthersize it to appDalegate.m file in in your map class

Comment: i did that. but now in first class from where i send data how can i set value. ? in application delegate class i defined variable like NSString *globalVariable; n set @property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *globalVariable;

Comment: write this appDalegate.yourvariable = @"setyourvalue";     And access this variable in destination class

Comment: and how can i acccess in destination?

Comment: What is appDelegate? where it is defined?

Comment: i got u but what is appDelegate?

Comment: appDalegate is object of yourapplicatonappDalegate class

Comment: ok fine then where should i define this object ? in first class? like my applicationdelegate class is bookTable. so in mapView.m bookTable *appDelegate? like this?

Comment: in my confirmController where i want this values in viewDidLoad method i used NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.reGlobal); it says undeclared identifier appDelegate?

Comment: you can access this value using appDalegate.varibale = currentclassvariable;

Comment: I accepted you answer thanku so much. how and where i can deallocate it?

Comment: Just let me know where n which variables i have to deallocate? Thanku so much mate. im struggling with this for last 4 days. Thanku so much . God Bless!!!

Comment: you most welcome .. always keep realse all variable in your dealloc method ..otherwise your applicaion has been crash .... you have to dealloc all varible wich you alloc ...if you dont dealloc than ok no problem but when you are working with major application you have to knowledge about deallcation otherwise you cant work on big applicaton

Comment: in applicationdelegate class as well? there i have to realease these global variable?  Actaually i am sending about 5 variable from first class to confirmController class. So is this ok with application? i will realese them.

Comment: yup  is it ok  if u dont know proper place for release than ignore to release variable .

Comment: I cant explain you  mate wot im feeling now. i have stuck on this for last 4 days. im serious. i was trying to send data through delegate mathod. but its so simple. i know we should not make global variables but its better to have something then nothing.

Comment: Actually just want to confirm that i have allocated appDelegate and appDelegate variable in applicationdelegate class only. so i deallocate from there. if i deallocate them into sender and receiving class application crashes. so no need to deallocate from there?